# Sort but ignore some patterns in sort?

Tags: bash, sorting

I am doing this

```
sort -f -t , -k 2,2 file -o file
```

Is there any way I can have it ignore certain patterns, eg "ABC" so I get this

```
Dog
ABCFrog
Lion
```

Or this

```
DogFrog
DogABCLion
DogZebra
```

Example of how I'm using it and what I want it to do.

From

```
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog ABC (C) http://AnotherUrl.com
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog (A) http://AnotherUrl.com
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog (B) http://AnotherUrl.com
```

To

```
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog (A) http://AnotherUrl.com
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog (B) http://AnotherUrl.com
http://randomUrl.com/icon.png, Dog ABC (C) http://AnotherUrl.com
```

I want the "ABC" to be skipped/ignored when sorting.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I suggest you show your inputs and expected outputs.  As it is, this question is a good candidate for closing.

Comment: What is your code for `sort`? Or is it an OS/shell command which would be on-topic elsewhere?

Comment: This is inside a shell script. Its not the end of the world if I cant skip a defined pattern when sorting, but it would be nice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as a question about one specific shell command, it belongs on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Ref: [When is it OK to ask shell scripting questions on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275757/1115360)

Comment: i disagree that it's off-topic because, although the question is ostensibly about one shell command, the desired I/O turned out to require an algorithmic solution involving multiple shell commands.

Comment: Chris, please accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

interesting question. i think the most convenient way to solve this is to temporarily remove the offending patterns, sort, then restore them.

one way to accomplish this is to remove the pattern from each string, but also include the original string on the same line after a delimiter, so that the `sort` operates on the first, patternless version, but the original version is preserved on the same line. then drop the patternless version:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\( ABC \)\?\(.*\)/\1 \3\t&/' file |
   sort -f -t , -k 2,2 |
   cut -f2
```

sample input:

```
url1, Dog ABC (C) url2
url1, Dog (A) url2
url1, Dog (B) url2
```

`sed` output:

```
url1, Dog (C) url2  url1, Dog ABC (C) url2
url1, Dog (A) url2  url1, Dog (A) url2
url1, Dog (B) url2  url1, Dog (B) url2
```

`sort` output:

```
url1, Dog (A) url2  url1, Dog (A) url2
url1, Dog (B) url2  url1, Dog (B) url2
url1, Dog (C) url2  url1, Dog ABC (C) url2
```

`cut` output:

```
url1, Dog (A) url2
url1, Dog (B) url2
url1, Dog ABC (C) url2
```